# Showing a window WPF that is already set/design

Tags: c#, wpf

I have already set/designed window, with textboxes, buttons, and all. When I need to open up this window.

```
Window win2 = new Window(); 
..
...
....

win2.Show();
```

I got a **NEW** `win2` with reset to default window properties like the sizes and my `textboxes` are gone.

How can I load my already set/designed window WPF?

Comment: Where did you (set/designed) or initialized all the controls

Answer (score 0):

Don't instantiate a new `Window`. You want to open *your* `Window`, so you need to use the name of *your* `Window`. Your code should be more like this:

```
YourWindow window = new YourWindow(); 
...
...
...
window.Show();
```

Obviously, you need to replace `YourWindow` with the *actual* name of the `Window` that you declared like:

```
public partial class YourWindow : Window { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to open the previously set Windows (win2) from another windows(win1)? if so, then do not dispose the win2. my approach is to create a property in win1

```
public Window2 Win2 {get; set;}
```

then in win1 Initialize()

```
Win2 = <previously set/designed win2>
```

then just call it when needed